# Modify Concatenate Formula to add an additional column (Mac Excel 2011)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I would like to modify this formula to ADD another column:

```
=IF(LEN(AK2),AK$1&": "&AK2,"")&IF(AND(LEN(AK2&AL2)>0,COUNTA(AK2:AL2)=2)," _
& ","")&IF(LEN(AL2),AL$1&": "&AL2,)
```

I would like to: concatenate 3 columns (AJ, AK and AL) - concatenated data will be entered into column V.

With the following resulting format:
- if there is a blank cell the Title and the blank field don't show up

Sample:

```
Column AJ |  Column AK  |  Column AL
 a info   |   b info    |   c info
```

- If AJ and AK are blank, this is what I want to see: Column C: C info
- If AK was blank, this is what I want to see: Column AJ: a info & Column AL: c info
- If AJ, AK and AK have info: Column AJ: a info & Column AK: b info & Column AL: c info

Comment: Your sample, I think, has a couple of typos. Where does column C come in to play? Also, third bullet point lists AK and AK twice. I'm a bit unclear, but I tried to clean up the formatting. Could you provide a little bit more detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your question, you want to include `header: Cell content` only if cell content is not empty. However your text description is much more complex, please clarify it if necessary.

Below formula does it exactly: only include data from column if the cell is not empty, it seems long, but the core is only half of it, I had to duplicate the formula to get rid of the " & " at the end:

`=IFERROR(LEFT(IF(AJ2<>"",AJ$1&": "&AJ2&" & ","")&IF(AK2<>"",AK$1&": "&AK2&" & ","")&IF(AL2<>"",AL$1&": "&AL2&" & ",""),LEN(IF(AJ2<>"",AJ$1&": "&AJ2&" & ","")&IF(AK2<>"",AK$1&": "&AK2&" & ","")&IF(AL2<>"",AL$1&": "&AL2&" & ",""))-3),"")`

[image]

Comment: Apologies for all my typos! You cleaned it up exactly right. I applied your revised formula (wow - so complex!) and it works perfectly if there is data in one or more of the 3 columns. However, if all 3 column are blank, it displays "#VALUE!". What needs to be adjusted? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @michele I've updated the formulas it won't give error.

Comment: The formula works perfectly now! I really appreciate your help!